# string.replace() with RegEx replaces wrong characters

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am trying to use a regex (javascript) to move periods in a text.
The text looks like this:

```
This is a text with ending period on wrong line
.
This is a another line
```

I use this regex:

```
summary.replace(/[\n\r]\.[\s\n\r]/gm, '.\r')
```

to make it look like this:

```
This is a text with ending period on wrong line.
This is a another line
```

But instead it looks like this:

```
This is a text with ending period on wrong line
.his is a another line
```

Cant figure out what is wrong in my regex.

Anyone?

Comment: how about /[\n\r]+\.[\s\n\r]/gm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex

```
[\n\r]+\.(?=[\s\n\r]+)
```

replace it with `.`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you output the result encoded as JSON with JSON.stringify to see if there are any whitespace characters (like newlines) that are still there. I would also use quantifiers for you character classes so that it can match more that one character at once

```
/[\n\r]?\.[\s\n\r]*/gm
```